Enumitem + color labels + multiline = bug?
In enumitem, suppose that I do style=multiline and use custom labels and then set font to be some color specification. Then the custom labels appear below the baseline. As you see, it does not happen with some other font specification like font=\scshape. It looks like a bug to me, but perhaps some TeX guru in here can make sense of this behavior:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color,enumitem}

\begin{document}
    
    \setlist[itemize]{style=multiline,labelwidth=2cm}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[First] Hello
        \item[Second] World
        \item[Third\\Fourth] Again
    \end{itemize}
    
    \setlist[itemize]{font=\scshape,style=multiline,labelwidth=2cm}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[First] Hello
        \item[Second] World
        \item[Third\\Fourth] Again
    \end{itemize}
    
    \setlist[itemize]{font=\color{red},style=multiline,labelwidth=2cm}
    
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[First] Hello
        \item[Second] World
        \item[Third\\Fourth] Again
    \end{itemize}
    
\end{document}



Hm, try \setlist[itemize]{ font=\color{red}\smash,style=multiline,labelwidth=2cm} (observe \smash)

@Zarko This works well, unless you actually do have a multi-line label. Try \label[Third\\Fourth]. It crashes painfully. (See my updated question.)

font=\leavevmode\color{red}.

\color{red} sets a whatsit in vertical mode, which will produce a box.
Hack: add \mbox{}.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color,enumitem}

\begin{document}

\section*{No color}

\begin{itemize}[style=multiline,labelwidth=2cm]
\item[First] Hello
\item[Second] World
\item[Third\\Fourth] Again
\end{itemize}

\section*{Colored}

\begin{itemize}[font=\mbox{}\color{red},style=multiline,labelwidth=2cm]
\item[First] Hello
\item[Second] World
\item[Third\\Fourth] Again
\end{itemize}

\end{document}


Your task is now to push the labels in some sensible position.

Nice solution. @UlrikeFischer suggested \leavevmode instead, which I guess works equally well, but is slightly cleaner IMO.

@Gaussler Whatever you prefer: \mbox is in the LaTeX manual, \leavevmode isn't.

If you compile with luatex, you can also try the luacolor package
\usepackage{luacolor}

It doesn't insert a color whatsits.
Example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color,enumitem}
\usepackage{luacolor}

\begin{document}

    \section*{No color}

    \setlist[itemize]{style=multiline,labelwidth=2cm}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item[First] Hello
        \item[Second] World
        \item[Third\\Fourth] Again
    \end{itemize}

    \section*{Small caps}

    \setlist[itemize]{font=\scshape,style=multiline,labelwidth=2cm}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item[First] Hello
        \item[Second] World
        \item[Third\\Fourth] Again
    \end{itemize}

    \section*{Colored}

    \setlist[itemize]{font=\color{red},style=multiline,labelwidth=2cm}

    \begin{itemize}
        \item[First] Hello
        \item[Second] World
        \item[Third\\Fourth] Again
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}


